# Is there a way to do this in JS? Instead of having to add each individual html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page that holds an empty div:

```
<html>
    <div id="HARBOURPAGE">
    </div>
<html>
```

I would like to append the following "grouped" html elements below using ONE JS expression inside hallTheme() function.

**All the html code below I'd like to append to the "HARBOURPAGE" div in one JS function call:**

```
<html>

<div id="mainDIV">
   <div id="div1">
   </div>
   <div id="div2">
   </div>
</div>

</html>
```

**The Javascript**
    function hallTheme(){

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

var node = document.createNode('div id="mobileHeader" style="position:relative;height:50px;width:100%;background-color:skyblue;">h2 id="heading" style="display: inline;padding-top: 10px;padding-left:5px;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 500;width: auto;font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;"color: #666;position: relative;top: 15px;">Example Title/h2>/div><!-- end header-->div id="mobileIntro" style="position:relative;height:115px;width:100%;text-align: center;display: inline-block;display: inline-block;">h3>About us/h3><p id="para" style="display:inline;font-size:14px;font-weight:500;width:auto;font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;color: #666;>Welcome to harbour!br>Browser our docks belowbr>Feel free to ask for anything/p>/div><!-- mobileBody -->div id="mobileInfo" style="position:relative;height:140px;width:100%;background-color:lightblue;text-align: center;">h3>Essentials/h3>p id="info">Useful information:br>bla bla br>/p>/div><!-- mobileBody -->"');

newDiv.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("HARBOURPAGE");
element.appendChild(newDiv);


}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do your JS in JS? This doesn't make much sense, please confirm the question

Comment: No, Is there a way to insert new html elements (elementS - so not just adding one extra div) into the existing div using that js function.

Comment: The issue I would like to circumvent is having to do redundantly: .createElement(<div 1>)...  .createElement(<div 2>) etc.

Comment: node.innerHTML? or maybe, just newDiv.InnerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding the question, edited the code

```
<html>
    <div class="HARBOURPAGE"></div>
<html>

function hallTheme(){
   document.getElementById("HARBOURPAGE").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mainDIV").outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need to add html elements, notice element's' to an empty html div using one JS function

Comment: @Jupiter Got that part and my code you only need to call this `hallTheme()` only once. Did I miss anything?

Comment: not quite what you did. There exists only one "HARBOURPAGE" div. The issue is that I cannot add all the html elements in one expression with createElement above.

Comment: @Jupiter which are those html elements that you want to append inside one HARBOURPAGE? Please update your question so that it is consistent with your comments

Comment: yes I have updated the question. I have simplified the html elements I wish to append.

Comment: @Jupiter I don't understand. I have updated my post as per your updated question. Can you verify if this is fine?

Comment: This will **a:** destroy any event-handlers bound to the existing elements, and **b:** result in elements with duplicate `id`s being present in the same document, immediately invalidating the HTML *and* (almost certainly) breaking other JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas I agree but I assumed that this is not the same code that OP will use as is.

Comment: You presented a solution you thought that the OP wouldn't use? I don't think that makes sense, but I am, perhaps, tired after a sleepless night. Oh, well...